# Unable to get image from Google User profile

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react web app, sometimes it doesn't load the image from the user profile. I'm using react.
It normally works, but sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the error that browser shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
async function singIngWithGoogle(){
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        
    const loginResult = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
      
        if(loginResult.user){
          const { displayName, photoURL, uid, email } = loginResult.user;
          
          if( !displayName || !photoURL ){
            throw new Error('Seu usuário Google não possui nome ou foto.');
          }

          setUser({
            id: uid,
            name: displayName,
            avatar: photoURL ?? {noUserImg},
            userEmail: email ?? ''
          })

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this attribute in your image tag in react js. `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"`

```
<img src="" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: because of a capital `P`, valid react syntax is `referrerPolicy="no-referrer"`